# How do I work with images in Bokeh (Python)

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, bokeh

For example you can plot an image in matplotlib using this code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img=mpimg.imread('image.png')
plt.imshow(img)
```

Is something like this possible with Bokeh(0.10)?

Comment: Not directly like this. Bokeh has `Image` (scalar data, to color map), `ImageRGBA` (raw RGBA data) and `ImageURL` (images loaded over the network). This would make a good feature request on the GitHub issue tracker.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `ImageURL` glyph (`image_url` plot method)to load images locally or from the web.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

output_file('image.html')

p = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1))
p.image_url(url=['tree.png'], x=0, y=1, w=0.8, h=0.6)
## could also leave out keywords
# p.image_url(['tree.png'], 0, 1, 0.8, h=0.6)  
show(p)
```

[image: Image Example]

One gotcha - if you graph only an image (and no other data), you'll have to explicitly set the plot ranges.

Here's the docs:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs.html#bokeh.models.glyphs.ImageURL

Comment: This example code no longer works on 0.12.5, I tried to edit the example code but it was rejected twice, you need to use the following call to image_url:  `p.image_url(url=['tree.png'], x=0, y=0, w=1, h=1, anchor="bottom_left")`

Comment: the example does not work when using the bokeh server. It is not able to find the image (404)

Comment: Is there a way to ensure the image is rendered 1:1 (Actual size, pixel for pixel, etc...)?

Answer (score 10):

The earlier answer was helpful. However, I wanted an image only option without any additional object. So, adding the answer for Bokeh version 0.12.0 and removed all the grids, axes and toolbar.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d

bosch_logo = "static/tree.jpg"
logo_src = ColumnDataSource(dict(url = [bosch_logo]))

page_logo = figure(plot_width = 500, plot_height = 500, title="")
page_logo.toolbar.logo = None
page_logo.toolbar_location = None
page_logo.x_range=Range1d(start=0, end=1)
page_logo.y_range=Range1d(start=0, end=1)
page_logo.xaxis.visible = None
page_logo.yaxis.visible = None
page_logo.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
page_logo.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
page_logo.image_url(url='url', x=0.05, y = 0.85, h=0.7, w=0.9, source=logo_src)
page_logo.outline_line_alpha = 0 
curdoc().add_root(page_logo)
```

Comment: ``figure`` is a convenience function that returns a ``bokeh.models.Plot`` instance with all of the axis/grids/tools set on it. Alternatively, you could instantiate a bare ``Plot`` object and add the image to that (avoided all of the subtraction stuff)

Comment: @Luke thanks for the comment, would it be possible for you to share a working code.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to display the image in a [div](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.markups.html).:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div

output_notebook()
div_image = Div(text="""<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/7.png" alt="div_image">""", width=150, height=150)
show(div_image)
```

[image: Squirtle sprite]

[ImageURL can't get updated dynamically with a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696216/bokeh-callback-for-image-update?rq=1). However, using a `div`, you can do so by treating the `div_image.text` as a regular Python string, for example:

```
from ipywidgets import interact

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, push_notebook
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div

output_notebook()
div_image = Div(text="""<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png" alt="div_image">""", width=100, height=100)

def update(pokemon_number=1):
    div_image.text = """<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/{}.png" alt="div_image">""".format(pokemon_number)
    push_notebook()

show(div_image, notebook_handle=True)

interact(update, pokemon_number=[1, 4, 7])
```

[image: Pokemon selector]

Of course, the image source can also point to a local file.

(Tested in Python 3.7.3 and bokeh 1.2.0)

Comment: I am trying to follow this answer with a local image, but Bokeh always displays the alt text.  Where am I going wrong?  ```"""<img src="/Users/me/Documents/Projects/Another Project/ABCD/ImageViewer/date_time_images/20201102/024744.png" alt="i_broken">"""```

Answer (score 5):

Running this example using bokeh serve is a bit more tricky. I suggest to setup working directory properly:

```
server_folder/
     +main.py
     +static/
         +logo.png
```

.. and run bokeh serve command from directory **ABOVE** server_folder

```
bokeh serve server_folder --show
```

Then this code works for me

```
#main.py file
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
x_range = (-20,-10) # could be anything - e.g.(0,1)
y_range = (20,30)
p = figure(x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range)
#img_path = 'https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/_static/images/logo.png'
img_path = 'server_folder/static/logo.png'
p.image_url(url=[img_path],x=x_range[0],y=y_range[1],w=x_range[1]-x_range[0],h=y_range[1]-y_range[0])
doc = curdoc()
doc.add_root(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that works, almost the same simple format as you requested:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np 
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

#load image
im = Image.open('Segment_image.png') # just replace any image that you want here


p = figure()
imarray = np.array(im.convert("RGBA"))

plotted_image = p.image_rgba(image=[imarray.view("uint32").reshape(imarray.shape[:2])], x=0, y=0, dw=imarray.shape[0], dh=imarray.shape[1])
show(p)
```