# Sliding through images with Bokeh Slider

Tags: javascript, python, slider, interactive, bokeh

I am trying to convey a large amount of scientific data seamlessly with the help of sliders.

I am beginning with Bokeh and have close to no knowledge in javascript. I tried to setup a first approach to be able to slide through two images, but I cannot get the image to refresh.

Suppose I have 1.png and 2.png in my folder.

```
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show

output_file('image.html')

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(url=['1.png']))

p = Figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1))

callbackimg = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var f = cb_obj.get('value')
    old = data['url'][0]
    data['url'][0]= old.replace("1","f")
    source.trigger('change');
""")

p.image_url('url',source=source, x=0, y=1,w=1,h=1)
slider = Slider(start=1, end=2, value=1, step=1, title="image number",     callback=callbackimg)

layout = vform(slider, p)
show(layout)
```

I adapted examples from [Bokeh Widget Doc](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#customjs-for-widgets) for the slider and 
[working with images in bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646270/how-do-i-work-with-images-in-bokeh-python).

My idea is that the slider, through the callbackimg snippet, will modify the source which contains the url, i.e the name of the image to load.
I thought, for now, that a simple access to the string in the source, and a replacement through the current value of the slider (so it should jump from 1.png to 2.png as the slider goes from 1 to 2) should do the trick.

However, nothing is changing. I suspect I am doing something wrong in the Javascript snippet.

Thanks for any feedback

EDIT: I edited the code according to the suggestions of @bigreddot, but now the slider shows simply an empty figure when sliding in position '2'.
EDIT2: Solved the issue, in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
url = data['url'][0]
url.replace("1","f")
```

The `replace` method returns a *new* string (which you immediately discard), so you are not actually changing anything in the column data source. You need something like:

```
old = data['url'][0]
data['url'] = old.replace("1","f")
```

Answer (score 2):

@bigreddot answer is correct, but var f is a number, so in the replace, I need to write f.toString(10).
Code that does what I want:

```
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show

output_file('image.html')

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(url=['1.png']))

p = Figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1))

callbackimg = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var f = cb_obj.get('value')
    old = data['url'][0]
    data['url'][0]= old.replace("1",f.toString(10))
    source.trigger('change');
""")

p.image_url('url',source=source, x=0, y=1,w=1,h=1)
slider = Slider(start=1, end=2, value=1, step=1, title="image number",     callback=callbackimg)

layout = vform(slider, p)
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample example where image changes as per the slider value. If slider value is 1 then app will display map-marker.png image and if value is 2 then app will display google_logo.png image.

With the help of Div you can do this task very easily.

map-marker.png [image: map-marker.png]

google_logo.png [image: google_logo.png]

Steps:

1. Create a folder named 'image' in **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/server/static** this path
2. After creating folder in above mentioned location copy google_logo.png and map-marker.png images to **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/server/static/image** this location. And save the following code as app.py and run it using **bokeh serve app.py --show** command.

   ```
   from bokeh.io import curdoc
   from bokeh.layouts import row
   from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, Div

   def change_img(attr, old, new):
       if slider.value == 1:
           logo.text = """<img src="static/image/map-marker.png"  alt="logo">"""
       else:
           logo.text = """<img src="static/image/google_logo.png"  alt="logo">"""

   slider = Slider(start=1, end=2, value=1, title="image number")
   slider.on_change('value', change_img)
   logo = Div(text="""<img src="static/image/logo.png"  alt="logo">""")

   curdoc().add_root(row(slider,logo))
   curdoc().title = "Image Demo"
   ```

[image: working]
app.py working

tested on bokeh version 0.12.13

Comment: Complementary to this solution, the `logo.text` can be changed dynamically treating it as a regular Python string, for example: `"""<img src="static/image/{}.png"  alt="logo">""".format(file_name)` (tested in Python 3.7.3 and bokeh 1.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create in advance a data source with all the image urls and use the slider to select the correct image.

Given the image names:

```
import pandas as pd
imgs = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']
df = pd.DataFrame(imgs, columns=['imgs'])
print(df.head())

     imgs
0   1.png
1   2.png
2   3.png
```

You can do:

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider, ColumnDataSource

source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1))
im = p.image_url(url=[source.data['imgs'][0]], x=0, y=1, w=1, h=1)

cb = CustomJS(args=dict(im=im, source=source), code="""
    im.data_source.data['url'] = [source.data['imgs'][cb_obj.value]];
    im.data_source.change.emit();
""")
slider = Slider(start=0, end=2, value=0, step=1, title="image number", callback=cb)
show(layout([slider, p]))
```