# Inserting RGBA picture in Bokeh (Python)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

I'd like to insert a picture as a background for a Bokeh plot. I converted the 1280 * 800 png file into an RGBA array as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646270/how-do-i-work-with-images-in-bokeh-python) using both `image_rgba` and `image_url` solutions, but rendering takes several minutes and the .html output cause my browser to crash.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
output_file('output.html')

img = mpimg.imread('image.png')
p = figure()
p.image_rgba(image=[img], x=[0], y=[799])
show(p)
```

Does this qualify as a bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: you may want to try `from scipy.misc import imread` rather than using the matplotlib `mpimg`.