# Can't make image_url work in Bokeh (Python)

Tags: image, python-3.x, bokeh

I tried to reproduce the solution from: [How do I work with images in Bokeh (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646270/how-do-i-work-with-images-in-bokeh-python) , but it doesn't work. For that, I find an image on the net and put it in place of the `'url'` field but the plot is just blank! From the original solution bokeh ask me to add up w and h params which I suppose are the width and height of the pic. Also I dropped x_range and y_range within figure() to wipe out the horizontal and vertical lines of the plot.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

p = figure()
p.image_url( url=[ "http://pngimg.com/uploads/palm_tree/palm_tree_PNG2504.png"], 
             x=1, y=1, w=253, h=409)
show( p)
```

Anyone could tell me what's going on ?

Comment: This is really a duplicate of the question that you had linked, I've updated the answer in the original post so that it works correctly on 0.12.5.

Answer (score 2):

Bokeh can't auto-range `ImageURL` it seems. So if there are no other glyphs, you need to provide explicit ranges. Additionlly, the default anchor is `upper_left` IIRC so it may be that our image is rendering off-canvas and you don't realize it. The code below works with Bokeh `0.12.5`:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
output_file("foo.html")

p = figure(x_range=(0,500), y_range=(0,500))
p.image_url( url=[ "http://pngimg.com/uploads/palm_tree/palm_tree_PNG2504.png"],
             x=1, y=1, w=253, h=409, anchor="bottom_left")
show(p)
```

Without the `anchor` set, the image plots blow the plot region (have to pan to see it)