# Using local images as markers in Bokeh for Python graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, bokeh, figure

I want to use local images as the markers on a figure rather than the provided shapes.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fprJz.png)
[image source](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.1/docs/reference/models/glyphs/image_url.html) So instead of:

```
slider_renderer = plt.square(x='x_mercator', y='y_mercator', source=payload_at_timestamp, size=20, color='lightskyblue')
```

Something like:

```
slider_renderer = plt.image(image='path/to/image', x='x_mercator', y='y_mercator', source=payload_at_timestamp, size=20, color='lightskyblue')
```

I've tried a few ways of doing this without success. In particular, using the [Bokeh image object](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.0/docs/reference/models/glyphs/image.html) didn't work as intended, with the interpreter complaining that the image was not part of the source dataframe:

```
quad_icon = skimage.io.imread('analysis_icons/quad.png')
slider_renderer = Image(image=[quad_icon], x='x_mercator', y='y_mercator', source=payload_at_timestamp)
```

I'm currently outputting the resulting figure in an HTML file, so hosting it locally with [bokeh serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055972/plotting-local-images-within-bokeh-serve-application) isn't a good option.

Comment: `image` is for taking 2d scalar arrays (i.e. arrays of numbers) and colormapping them. Your best bet would be to convert the images to 2d RGBA numpy arrays, and use `image_rgba` instead. There is no built-in facility for displaying image files directly (except via URLs with `image_url`)

Comment: Thanks, let me give this a try.