# UnsetValueError while plotting WordCloud using bokeh package

Tags: python, bokeh, word-cloud, wordcloud2

Here is the code I am using to generate a word cloud using bokeh library in python. The current python, bokeh, and bokeh_wordcloud2 version(s) are 3.7.6, 1.4.0, and 0.9 respectively.

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh_wordcloud2 import WordCloud2

data = [['susan',6], ['tom',3], ['frankie',8],
        ['roger',7], ['amy',9], ['nicole',10],
        ['joran',5], ['mark',4], ['brianne',7],
        ['michael',8], ['greg',4], ['adrian',6], ['drew',9]]
names,weights = zip(*data)
test1 = ColumnDataSource({'names':names,'weights':weights})
wordcloud = WordCloud2(source=test1,wordCol="names",sizeCol="weights",color="pink")
show(wordcloud)
```

##### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsetValueError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b167ef5d6ae0> in <module>
     14 # we will specify just "blue" for the color
     15 wordcloud = WordCloud2(source=test1,wordCol="names",sizeCol="weights",color="pink")
---> 16 show(wordcloud)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\bokeh\io\showing.py in show(obj, browser, new, notebook_handle, notebook_url, **kw)
    137         return run_notebook_hook(state.notebook_type, 'app', obj, state, notebook_url, **kw)
    138 
--> 139     return _show_with_state(obj, state, browser, new, notebook_handle=notebook_handle)
    140 
    141 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\bokeh\core\property\descriptors.py in __get__(self, obj, owner)
    502                 return value
    503             else:
--> 504                 raise UnsetValueError(f"{obj}.{self.name} doesn't have a value set")
    505         elif owner is not None:
    506             return self

UnsetValueError: WordCloud2(id='1002', ...).click doesn't have a value set
```

I see that `click` is expecting a JS Instance for input ==> `click: expected an instance of type CustomJS`. Please suggest if there is a fix/workaround for the above-mentioned error.

Also, suggest if there is an easy way to generate word clouds using bokeh?

Comment: You must have an environment mixup. You can't be using Bokeh 1.4 because `UnsetValueError` is much newer than that (it was only added in Bokeh 2.3 last year). That package needs to be updated for recent Bokeh versions, or you need to downgrade n Bokeh.

Comment: @bigreddot, I am using bokeh 1.4.0 python 3.7.6 since and my new requirement is to plot word cloud for NLP-related use cases. Is there any other way I can generate word clouds using bokeh (or) any other package and then parse it to bokeh doc/curdoc obj?

Comment: You think you are using Bokeh 1.4, but you are mistaken. You literally cannot be using Bokeh 1.4 and see that error message, because the `UnsetValueError` mentioned at the end of the stack trace *did not exist in version 1.4*. It was added , last year, for version **2.3**, in [this PR](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/10842). If you don't believe me, print out the value of `bokeh.__version__` at the top of your code.

Comment: @bigreddot, my apologies, I am trying this both in python notebook and in my application which has 2 different environments. The ideal scenario is 1.4.0 V. I am getting the same error while running this code in my application as well.

Comment: No apologies needed. But until or unless the authors of WordCloud2 updated their library to work with newer Bokeh versions, then using an old 1.x version of Bokeh is the only option. (Or else don't use the WordCloud2 library at all) If you are getting the same error in the application then your application must also be using Bokeh >= 2.3, full stop.